# How to un-hover an element on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, hover

I have a drop down element which works great on desktop. 
http://www.c-testing.nl/werkenbijvanaarsen/growing-together/

But on mobile devices, the drop down won't collapse back when tapping again.
I read some answers on this forum, but it doesn't seem to work in this case.

I'm trying to achieve this only with css, but the more I read about this, it seems that online javascript can achieve it.

Does anybody know how I can set something like an un-hover on this element?

`.pl-drop_down:hover ul {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}`

Best regards, Mark

Answer (score 3):

It’s unlikely you’ll get what you want using just CSS :hover, as this wasn’t designed for touch screens.

To get it to collapse back on mobile, you could add the javascript:

`$('[selector that you want to tap]').click(function() {
    $('.pl-drop_down').css({'pointer-events': 'none'});
});`

This will remove the hover state on mobile and should make it collapse back, you’ll need jQuery for this solution to work though.

Comment: Hi Jordan,

Thanks for your reply.
Unfortunitaly that doesn't work in this case.

I put this script in de Wordpress functions.php

`<script type="text/javascript">
$('.pl-drop_down.wf').click(function() {
    $('.pl-drop_down').css({'pointer-events': 'none'});
});
</script>`

I suppose jquery is already working in the website, so I think that's not the problem.

Am I doing something wrong do you think?

Comment: Hi Jordan, There I am again.
I did some extra research and I saw, for Wordpress websites, I have to place the script between soms extras. Now this is the script:
`( function($) {
$('.pl-drop_down.wf').click(function() {
    $('.pl-drop_down').css({'pointer-events': 'none'});
});
} ) ( jQuery );`

But first I see that after collapsing back I can't open the toggle again. It also applies to the desktop version. Can I do something about that?
Greets Mark

Comment: You have to set `{'pointer-events': 'auto'}` to enable hover events again. You might have to call `blur()` on the element before to prevent immediately getting the hover event agein.